# unexpected symbol near '<='

Tags: lua, coronasdk

It would be so wonderful if it would tell me what the unexpected symbol is but alas it doesn't. Can someone please advice me what is wrong with this:

```
for i = 1, 100 do
if i <= 3 then
local rowMenu = 1
elseif <= 6 then
local rowMenu = 2
elseif <= 9 then
local rowMenu = 3
elseif <= 12 then
local rowMenu = 4
elseif <= 15 then
local rowMenu = 5
elseif <= 18 then
local rowMenu = 6
elseif <= 21 then
local rowMenu = 7
elseif <= 24 then
local rowMenu = 8
end
end
```

I plan on calculated the placement of objects within the loop - its not complete - but I don't understand why this shouldnt work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complier is telling you that after seeing `elseif` it expected something that starts an expression but it found `<=`, which doesn't.

You need to mention `i` explicitly in all tests:

```
elseif i <= 6 then
```

Note that these chains of ifs can be replaced by

```
rowMenu = 3*math.ceil(i/3)
```

or

```
rowMenu = 3*((i//3)+(i*i)%3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining that to me. math.ceil will be useful for many things!

Comment: Another problem with the OP's code is the assignment to `local rowMenu` inside the IF block(s) which will make `rowMenu` invisible afterwards.